# How to draw the calculation of a determinant?

Tags: math-mode, equations, matrices, alignment

I'm trying to reproduce the following calculation of a determinant in LaTeX:

[image: example image]

Any ideas? I thought of using the `tabular` environment but unfortunately I'm not able to align the "=" correctly.

Comment: Please, add a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), so the people could easily think and try with your problem.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> I just have one question: The numbers in the determine itself are all
>   right aligned. You can see it in column 3, row 1 and 2 in the picture
>   I posted. The 2 is just above the -2 and they are both right aligned,
>   no matter if there is a minus or not. Do you have any idea how to
>   realize that?
>   -- user24295

No, I don't, but according to comments by percusse and Manuel you can do that by loading **mathtools** instead of **amsmath** and use `\begin{vmatrix*}[r] … \end{vmatrix*}`. I haven't checked though by myself. But I do recomment keep the standard alignement provided by `\begin{vmatrix} ... \end{vmatrix}`.

---

UPDATE with **align**. Thanks to cmhughes's advice I've replaced `eqnarray` with `align`and `&=&` with `&=`. ADDED. As commented by egreg `eqnarray` should be avoided (see e.g. [here](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/madsen.pdf) and [here](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf)) due to spacing discrepancies.

The **updated code** is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\det A &=\left. 
\begin{array}{c}
\;\;\text{*)} \\ 
-1\text{)} \\ 
-2\text{)} \\ 
-2\text{)}
\end{array}
\right. 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & -6 \\ 
1 & 2 & -2 & -5 \\ 
2 & 4 & -2 & -9 \\ 
2 & 4 & -6 & -9  \notag
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & -6 \\ 
0 & -1 & -4 & 1 \\ 
0 & -2 & -6 & 3 \\ 
0 & -2 & -10 & 3
\end{vmatrix}
\\ \notag
&& \\ 
&=\left. 
\begin{array}{c}
\;\;\text{*)} \\ 
-2\text{)} \\ 
-2\text{)}
\end{array}
\right. 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 4 & 1 \\ 
2 & 6 & 3 \\ 
2 & 10 & 3
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 4 & 1 \\ 
0 & -2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
-2 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
=-4\notag
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The **Output** is:

[image]

---

We can use the following code (with **eqnarray**)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}
\det A\; &=&\left. 
\begin{array}{c}
\;\;\text{*)} \\ 
-1\text{)} \\ 
-2\text{)} \\ 
-2\text{)}
\end{array}
\right. 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & -6 \\ 
1 & 2 & -2 & -5 \\ 
2 & 4 & -2 & -9 \\ 
2 & 4 & -6 & -9
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & -6 \\ 
0 & -1 & -4 & 1 \\ 
0 & -2 & -6 & 3 \\ 
0 & -2 & -10 & 3
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&& \\
&=&\left. 
\begin{array}{c}
\;\;\text{*)} \\ 
-2\text{)} \\ 
-2\text{)}
\end{array}
\right. 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 4 & 1 \\ 
2 & 6 & 3 \\ 
2 & 10 & 3
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 4 & 1 \\ 
0 & -2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
-2 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
=-4
\end{eqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

to type

[image]

Comment: Please, don't recommend `eqnarray` under any circumstances.

Comment: Very nice except the [`eqnarray`. Here is one out of many reasons](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align). (vote capped for today)

Comment: `s/eqnarray/align/g` and `s/&=&/&=/g` should do the trick

Comment: Very nice done. Thank you @Américo Tavares for your help. I just have one question: The numbers in the determine itself are all right aligned. You can see it in column 3, row 1 and 2 in the picture I posted. The 2 is just above the -2 and they are both right aligned, no matter if there is a minus or not. Do you have any idea how to realize that?

Comment: @user24295 I don't know how to have positive and negative numbers right aligned in the `\begin{vmatrix} ... \begin{vmatrix}` environment.

Comment: @egreg. I will try to change the `eqnarray` environment to a more adequate one, but now that you have an answer with the `align*` it will be difficult. You are right, the document you indicated says: "Although the standard eqnarray environment remains available, it is better to
use align or equation+split instead."

Comment: @cmhughes Could you please elaborate a bit because I don't understand your advice?

Comment: sure :) search and replace `eqnarray` with `align`. And then search and replace `&=&` with `&=`

Comment: @AméricoTavares To right align the columns you could use `\begin{vmatrix*}[r] … \end{vmatrix*}`.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks. I've tried to use the option `[r]` in all `\begin{vmatrix*}[r] ... \end{vmatrix*}`, but I got an error message. I have no explanation.

Comment: @Manuel For that to work you need to load [`mathtools`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathtools) instead which is better than `amsmath` anyway. It's specifically written on top of  `amsmath` and also fixes/improves it .

Comment: @Manuel Thanks. The section 4.1 Matrices of [User’s Guide for the amsmath Package](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) says: "unlike the array environment, you don’t have to
give column specifications for any of the matrix environments; by default you
can have up to 10 centered columns.2 (If you need left or right alignment in a
column or other special formats you must resort to array.)"

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks! I've updated the code in accordance with your comment.

Comment: @percusse Argh! I forgot that. By the way, Américo, read what *percusse* said. If you load the `mathtools` package (which is an «improvement» of `amsmath`) you can use what I said.

Comment: Thank you all for your great help. I've tried @Américo Tavares solution with the mathtools instead of amsmath an `\begin{vmatrix*}[r]...\end{vmatrix*}`. It works like a charm. I also like to thank @percusse for the idea using mathtools.

Answer (score 13):

You can define an `xvmatrix` environment for the "eXtended" matrix, where you specify the coefficients as a first column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{xvmatrix}% eXtended vmatrix
  {\left.\array{@{}r |@{\,}*\c@MaxMatrixCols c}}
  {\endarray\kern-\arraycolsep\right|}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\det A &=
\begin{xvmatrix}
 *) & 1 & 3 &  2 & -6 \\ 
-1) & 1 & 2 & -2 & -5 \\ 
-2) & 2 & 4 & -2 & -9 \\ 
-2) & 2 & 4 & -6 & -9
\end{xvmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & -6 \\ 
0 & -1 & -4 & 1 \\ 
0 & -2 & -6 & 3 \\ 
0 & -2 & -10 & 3
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&=
\begin{xvmatrix}
 *) & 1 &  4 & 1 \\ 
-2) & 2 &  6 & 3 \\ 
-2) & 2 & 10 & 3
\end{xvmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 4 & 1 \\ 
0 & -2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
-2 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
=-4
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update 2020

You can use the `nicematrix` package.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\det A &=
\begin{vNiceMatrix}[first-col]
 *) & 1 & 3 &  2 & -6 \\ 
-1) & 1 & 2 & -2 & -5 \\ 
-2) & 2 & 4 & -2 & -9 \\ 
-2) & 2 & 4 & -6 & -9
\end{vNiceMatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & -6 \\ 
0 & -1 & -4 & 1 \\ 
0 & -2 & -6 & 3 \\ 
0 & -2 & -10 & 3
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&=
\begin{vNiceMatrix}[first-col]
 *) & 1 &  4 & 1 \\ 
-2) & 2 &  6 & 3 \\ 
-2) & 2 & 10 & 3
\end{vNiceMatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 4 & 1 \\ 
0 & -2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
-2 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1
\end{vmatrix}
=-4
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And if that's always the notation, you could add `)` to the environment so you don't need to write it all the times. Apart from that, I don't find this notation pleasant (`*)`, etc. on the left of the matrix), I don't suggest any other, but I think this is not beautiful.

Comment: @Manuel I thought about adding the `)` to the definition, but maybe leaving it in the cell makes clearer what the number is for. I don't like the notation, either. There's no need to use the Laplace development at any stage, the usual Gaussian elimination suffices.

Comment: Nitpicking: In the OP's picture, the numbers are right aligned.

Comment: @mafp I never right align the coefficients of a matrix. Adding that feature is possible, though.

Comment: @egreg Oh, I would not write the whole determinant computation that way. But it is what the OP asked for. It works with `mathtools`, and then `vmatrix[r]`, right?

Answer (score 9):

I do not consider a good habit introducing such a notation, my experience is that it only confuses people. Mathematical formalism is there for a reason. You can try the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \det A&=
  \underbrace{\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
    -2 & 0 & 0 & 1
  \end{vmatrix}}_{=1}
  \cdot
  \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 3 & 2 & -6 \\ 
    1 & 2 & -2 & -5 \\ 
    2 & 4 & -2 & -9 \\ 
    2 & 4 & -6 & -9
  \end{vmatrix}
  =
  \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 3 & 2 & -6 \\ 
    0 & -1 & -4 & 1 \\ 
    0 & -2 & -6 & 3 \\ 
    0 & -2 & -10 & 3
  \end{vmatrix}
  \\
  &=
  \underbrace{\begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    -2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
    -2 & 0 & 1
  \end{vmatrix}}_{=1}
  \cdot
  \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 4 & 1 \\ 
    2 & 6 & 3 \\ 
    2 & 10 & 3
  \end{vmatrix}
  =
  \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 4 & 1 \\ 
    0 & -2 & 1 \\ 
    0 & 2 & 1
  \end{vmatrix}
  =
  \begin{vmatrix}
    -2 & 1 \\ 
    2 & 1
  \end{vmatrix}
  =-4
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Somehow, it would make more sense if you tried to demonstrate the column manipulation, because then the triangle unit-determinant matrix would come on the right side. But even this is completely clear IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another style I made. If you aren't doing determinants, replace the "vmatrix" with "bmatrix". I don't know how to post a picture of what it looks like.

[image]

```
\paragraph{Example}
Evaluate the determinant
\begin{align*}
  \begin{vmatrix*}[r]
        1 & -12 & 5 & -3 \\
        2 & -21 & 22 & -7 \\
        2 & -9 & 41 & -10 \\
        0 & 3 & 7 & 3
    \end{vmatrix*}.
\end{align*}

\paragraph{Solution}
\begin{align*}
  \begin{vmatrix*}[r]
        1 & -12 & 5 & -3 \\
        2 & -21 & 22 & -7 \\
        2 & -9 & 41 & -10 \\
        0 & 3 & 7 & 3
    \end{vmatrix*}
    &=
  \begin{vmatrix*}[r]
        1 & -12 &  5 & -3 \\
        0 &   3 & 12 & -1 \\
        0 &  15 & 31 & -4 \\
        0 &   3 &  7 &  3
    \end{vmatrix*}
    \quad
    \begin{matrix*}[l]
        \\ 
        \leftarrow -2r_1+r_2 \ \text{\scriptsize (no change in determinant)} \\
        \leftarrow  -2r_2+r_3 \ \text{\scriptsize (no change in determinant)} \\
        \\
    \end{matrix*} \\
    &=
  -\begin{vmatrix*}[r]
        1 & -3 &  5 & -12 \\
        0 & -1 & 12 &   3 \\
        0 & -4 & 31 &  15 \\
        0 &  3 &  7 &   3
    \end{vmatrix*}
    \quad
    \begin{matrix*}[l]
        \\ 
        \leftarrow c_2 \leftrightarrow c_4 \ \text{\scriptsize (negate determinant)} \\
        \\
        \\
    \end{matrix*} \\
    &=
  -\begin{vmatrix*}[r]
        1 & -3 &   5 & -12 \\
        0 &  1 & -12 &  -3 \\
        0 &  4 & -31 & -15 \\
        0 &  3 &   7 &   3
    \end{vmatrix*}
    \quad
    \begin{matrix*}[l]
        \\ 
        \leftarrow -r_2 \ \text{\scriptsize (negate determinant)} \\
        \leftarrow -r_3 \ \text{\scriptsize (negate determinant)} \\
        \\
    \end{matrix*} \\
    &=
  -\begin{vmatrix*}[r]
        1 & -3 &   5 & -12 \\
        0 &  1 & -12 &  -3 \\
        0 &  0 &  17 &  -3 \\
        0 &  0 &  43 &  12
    \end{vmatrix*}
    \quad
    \begin{matrix*}[l]
        \\ 
        \\ 
        \leftarrow -4r_2+r_3 \ \text{\scriptsize (no change in determinant)} \\
        \leftarrow -3r_2+r_4 \ \text{\scriptsize (no change in determinant)}
    \end{matrix*} \\
    &=
  -17\begin{vmatrix*}[r]
        1 & -3 &   5 & -12 \\
        0 &  1 & -12 &  -3 \\
        0 &  0 &   1 &  -\nicefrac{3}{17} \\
        0 &  0 &  43 &  12
    \end{vmatrix*}
    \quad
    \begin{matrix*}[l]
        \\ 
        \\ 
        \leftarrow \nicefrac{1}{17}r_3 \ \text{\scriptsize (factor out 17)} \\
        \\
    \end{matrix*} \\
    &=
  -17\begin{vmatrix*}[r]
        1 & -3 &   5 & -12 \\
        0 &  1 & -12 &  -3 \\
        0 &  0 &   1 &  -\nicefrac{3}{17} \\
        0 &  0 &  0 &  \nicefrac{333}{17}
    \end{vmatrix*}
    \quad
    \begin{matrix*}[l]
        \\ 
        \\ 
        \\ 
        \leftarrow -43r_3+r_4 \ \text{\scriptsize (no change in determinant)}
    \end{matrix*} \\
    &= -17\left(\frac{333}{17}\right) = \bm{-333}.
\end{align*}
```